# React Native expo-cli can't find module expo.js

Tags: react-native, expo

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Jobay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12
)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error came to becose expo cli can't install poperlay. so we need to install expo cli perfectly .

You can try this comman it's work perfectly fine.

```
npm install -g expo-cli --force
```